# computation of conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I've some confusion about when to use which approach for calculating the conditional probabilities.

Case 1: why not just directly 2/6 and need to use the multiplication rule? It seems to me just simple counting. In this case both 2/6 and the conditional multiplication gives the same result. Is that just a coincidence? And what exactly are the relationship between these 2 methods?

[image: Case 1]

Case 2: When do we use numbers, or percentage as both the numerator and denominator of conditional probabilities? In contrast with case 1 above, when do we know we need to just do simply counting on the numbers/probabilities to construct our conditional probabilities and when to apply multiplication rules? I think the boundaries between those two are very blur to me.
[image: case 2]

Specifically, I'm wondering what are the conditions for using either approach? And what's the relation between these approaches? TIA.

Comment: Can you explain where you are getting "2/6"? If the two comes from "select two people" and the six comes from "six supervisors in research," then this does not make any sense for computing "probability that a group of two people are both from research." Another way to see that this reasoning is wrong is that you can change the number of supervisors in development but your answer would remain the same.

Comment: $(2/6)$ just coincidentally provides the same answer, in Case 1.  Alter the problem somewhat.  Suppose that $(3)$ supervisors are to be selected, instead of $(2)$ and you want to know the probability that all $(3)$ supervisors come from research?  Would you then presume that the probability of this occurring is $\frac{3}{6}$?  ...see next comment

Comment: Now, alter the original problem in a different direction.  You are choosing $2$ supervisors, just as before, but instead of their being $4$ supervisors in development, there are $5$ supervisors in development.  This means that instead of there being $10$ supervisors in total, there would be $11$ supervisors.  Does it seem intuitively reasonable to you that the probability that both supervisors come from research would still be $(2/6)$, independent of how many development supervisors there are?

Comment: For what it's worth, you are asking a deeper question than you may realize.  In my opinion, the study of Probability Theory demands that you stretch your intuition.  This means that you have to be exposed to perhaps $(50)$ problems of a certain type, so you completely understand why the recommended approach is valid.  Also, I consider sanity-checking with a computer program indispensable.  This way, you can independently verify the accurate computation.  If you have no programming experience, then I recommend Python, as a first language, rather than Java or C.

Comment: @angryavian ah, i see why 2/6 is so wrong. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @user2661923, thanks for substantitating on angryavian's. I agree. And for the deeper part, that's indeed my feeling that several methods to compute the same thing in probability sometimes can be confusing. And thanks for the useful suggestion. Would you mind substantiating on how to write program for such sanity check?

Comment: Pseudocode: Outer Loop: I1 : 1 thru 10.  Inner Loop: I2 : 1 thru 10.  If I1 = I2, ignore and skip to the next iteration.  Else, Denominator = Denominator + 1.  Then, If I1 < 7 and I2 < 7, Numerator = Numerator + 1.

Comment: @user2661923, sorry...would you elaborate more on why this work for this problem please?

Comment: Assume that the research supervisors are assigned the numbers $1$ thru $6$ and that the development supervisors are assigned the numbers $7$ thru $10$.  As you loop thru I1 :1 thru 10 and I2: 1 thru 10, you are looping thru $(10 \times 10)$ possibilities.  The $(10)$ possibilities where I1 and I2 are equal are ignored.  So, now, you are focusing on the $90$ possibilities where I1 and I2 are not equal.  Setting the denominator to $90$ corresponds to sampling, without replacement, where the order of selection is deemed important.  ...see next comment

Comment: So, the numerator must be computed in a consistent manner, where (again), order of selection is deemed important.  Incrementing the numerator by 1, when and only when I1 and I2 are both $< 7$ (and I1, I2 are different from each other) corresponds to both supervisors coming from research.